# How to add Ad id to Facebook URL

Tags: facebook, dynamic, parameters, tags, dynamicparameters

we want add to Facebook URL a parameter that send the Ad-ID (unique id Facebook generate).
Its actually a dynamic parameter which get different ID per Ad.
is this possible ?